# Rails: passing arguments through controller methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

Say I've got a standard `new` method in a controller:

```
def new
  @doc = Doc.new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @doc }
  end
end
```

How would I facilitate passing an argument through it, i.e.:

```
def new(i)
  ...
end
```

To permit me to write something like this in the view:

```
<%= link_to(e.name, new_doc_path(e.id)) %>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rails doesn't work like that. If you want to pass anything to the controller you have to use the `params` hash. In your example:

View:

```
<%= link_to(e.name, new_doc_with_parameter_path(e.id)) %>
```

Controller:

```
def new
  id = params[:id]
  # do something with `id`
end
```

For this to work you have to change your routes so that you can pass an `id` via the URL to your new action:

```
get "/docs/new/:id" => "docs#new", :as => :new_doc_with_parameter
```

Although the above *should* work, in your case it may be better to have a look at [Nested Resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

Comment: That seems like it'll work, but `new_doc_path(e.id)` gives me a URL that looks like `.../doc/new.3`. Any thoughts?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? What kind of object is `e`? You may want to have a look at [Nested Resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

Comment: @mileorsohigh, I updated my answer, but it may be better to use Nested Resources. Not sure if that's appropriate in your situation though.

Comment: `e` loops through records from a different model and each `doc` record has to record which `e` was selected. Does that makes sense?

Comment: So `Doc belongs_to :e` in your model? If so, you can use nested resources. See my link above. If not, try my updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I'll give the nested resources a go: it seems like a better idea. Thanks for you help!